# Web RecordRtc video recording does not work in safari and ios, android browser

Tags: webrtc, recordrtc

Is there any solution to run Web Record RTC on safari and ios,androind browser?
I have implemented fully code for video recording in php but it could not work in safari & ios,android browser.
Do Anyone have idea that how to enable usermedia in safari & ios, androind browser.

Answer (score 0):

Safari on the Mac and iOS does not support webRTC. In the browser or webview, webRTC is not supported, which means that getUserMedia is not available, which means that you can't stream video to your web RecordRTC.

If you want to do webRTC, you will have to write native code, or there is a cordova plugin for ios at https://github.com/eface2face/cordova-plugin-iosrtc - this is on the bleeding edge right now, so be ready for some frustration

It is supported on android. The native android browser may or may not work, depending on what your device is. Install chrome and it will work. If you are doing Android webapps, you should use the crosswalk plugin, as it basically provides chrome instead of webview, and then you know that webRTC support is there.

Comment: Thank you for your response. But in web view safari browser is not allowing Web RecordRTC

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer to provide more detail for you